# Hibernate Inheritance.TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I am having a very huge problem with hibernate.

My inheritance strategy works perfectly under eclipselink as the jpa provider, both under glassfish and jboss application servers, but when i switch to hibernate, everything goes heywire.

I have read several posts here but none solves my problem.

The following is the stacktrace.

```
Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.UnionSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2011)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:765)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3406)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3360)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1334)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1724)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
```

I have made sure that no subclass defines another @Id column (In any case, netbeans will always flag for me this error)

These is one set of inheritance i have:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@PartialSecurity
public abstract class DataVerification extends SecureEntity implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = IdGenerator.serialVersionUID(DataVerification.class);
  @Id
  private Long verificationId = IdGenerator.generateId();
  @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String verificationCode;
  private String verifiedId;
  private boolean verified;
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Calendar verificationDate;
  private DataVerificationType dataVerificationType;
  private VerificationMethod verificationMethod;
  @OneToOne
  private Account verifiedBy;
  @OneToOne
  private Account approvedBy;


/**
 *
 * @author marembo
 */
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class OnlineDataVerification extends DataVerification implements Serializable {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Ignore
  private List<UploadFile> verificationFiles;


    /**
     *
     * @author marembo
     */
    @Entity
    public class IncomeDataVerification extends OnlineDataVerification implements Serializable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = IdGenerator.serialVersionUID(IncomeDataVerification.class);
      private IncomeSource incomeSource;
      private String occupation;


/**
 *
 * @author marembo
 */
@Entity
public class AgentDataVerification extends OnlineDataVerification implements Serializable {

  @Column(length = 2048, nullable = false)
  private String comment;
  private String verificationTransaction = IdGenerator.generateStringId();
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you send the base class and subclasses?

Comment: I have several inheritance as i am working with a very huge project, but i am posting a few of them

Comment: This exception is usually caused by a duplicate @Id but you said you made sure there wasn't any.

Comment: @spaniard sure i did. I have been programming under netbeans, and netbeans always flags this issue. See the update for a sample inheritance i have in my project

Comment: A comment aside of this issue, there is no need to implement `Serializable` in all the class hierarchy as long as the base class does.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace raise suspicion for hibernate version inconsistency problem. If you deploy your app to JBoss, JBoss already has its own hibernate. If your war also came with Hibernate of different version, the actual classes loaded on the classpath might be inconsistent causing all sorts of problem.

Normally best practice is if you're deploying to container that already provide hibernate don't bundle it inside your war (eg: mark dependency as provided on maven pom)

Comment: I dont even have hibernate as a dependency, since i do not require it at compile time